# Why is Bitcoin core deleting my blk files while downloading blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

I want to download the bitcoin blockchain to actually be able to parse it using the blk files, but as I'm seeing right now while installing, bitcoin core is deleting them and keeps downloading newer ones but I want to have everything related to block headers not transaction data. Is there a way to keep everything or only block headers ?

Thanks,

Comment: This sounds like you have pruning enabled. If pruning is off, no blk*.dat file should ever be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Run bitcoind or bitcoin-qt with `-prune=0`. If you are using bitcoin-qt and pruning was enabled when it was run for the first time, you can disable it in settings -> options.